# What is the equation (or equations) to find the sequence/s of odd numbers that are the result of the sum of two squares?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

(not including $0^2 + b^2$ and only including odd numbers:)

Starting at $5 = 1^2 + 2^2$
then
$13 = 2^2 + 3^2$
$17 = 4^2 + 1^2$
$25 = 3^2 + 4^2$
$29 = 2^2 + 5^2$
What is the equation/s to find the
$\space n^{th}\space $
number in the sequence (eg: what number is the
$\space 397^{th}\space $
number or
$\space 100,578^{th}\space $ number in the sequence/s?) If someone were to have found this equation would that be new?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, please read [Sum of squares function for $k = 2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares_function#k_=_2). Also, I don't see what your question has to do with [tag:complex-analysis].

Comment: I doubt there is a nice closed formula for the $n$th such number, but the conditions are known, so one can write a program to find it.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Krish Devi  My answer does not seem popular. Can you provide more numbers in the series?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A339952

Comment: I have edited my answer again. I believe I have shown that what you ask is not possible or at least extremely difficult but I have shown how your criteria can be met locally. As I asked before: Please provide feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer, I show it is unlikely that a single formula exists to meet your [global] criteria –– that it is only possible to meet your criteria on a set by set basis.

The numbers in the question are hypotenuse values of the first five [smallest primitive] Pythagorean triples in order of size. The following formula generate $\space sets\space$ of $\space C$-values from all  triples where
$\space GCD(A,B,C)=(2x-1)^2, x\in\mathbb{N},\space$  which includes all primitives and a few odd square multiples of primitives. These are the
$\space values \space$  in the table  below.

$$C=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k+2k^2$$

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c} 
n & k=1 & k=2 & k=3 & k=4 & k=5   &  k=6  & \cdots\\ \hline
Set_1 & 5 & 13& 25& 41& 61 & \underline{\mathit{85}} \\ \hline
Set_2 & 17 & 29 & \mathbf{45} & \underline{\mathit{65}} & 89 & 117 \\ \hline
Set_3 & 37 & 53 & 73 & 97 & \mathbf{125} & 157 \\ \hline
Set_4 &  \underline{\mathit{65}} &    \underline{\mathit{85}} & 109 & 137 & 69 & 205 \\ \hline
Set_5 &101 & 125 & \mathbf{153} & 185 & 221 & 261 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$
The $\textbf{bold}$ numbers are from imprimitive triples and those
$\underline{\textit {underlined italic}}$ are duplicates among primitive triples.

There will be an imprimitive any time
$GCD\big(2(n-1),k\big)>1.$

There are $\space 2^{f-1} \space $ duplicates where
$ \space f \space $ is then number of distinct prime factors of $\space C.$

Arranging the table entries in order of size, we can appreciate the difficulty of finding a pattern in the
$\space (n,k) \space$ values needed to generate this order. If we enlarge the list to include more sets or higher $\space k$-values, the sequence changes, even in the middle of the list shown.

\begin{align*}
F(1,1)&= (5)  = 1^2 + 2^2\\  
F(1,2)&= (13) = 3^2 + 2^2\\  
F(2,1)&= (17) = 1^2 + 4^2\\  
F(1,3)&= (25) = 3^2 + 4^2\\  
F(2,2)&= (29) = 5^2 + 2^2\\ 
F(3,1)&= (37) = 1^2 + 6^2\\  
F(1,4)&= (41) = 5^2 + 4^2\\  
F(2,3)&= (45) = 3^2 + 6^2\\  
F(3,2)&= (53) = 7^2 + 2^2\\  
F(1,5)&= (61) = 5^2 + 6^2\\ 
F(2,4)&= (65) = 1^2 + 8^2 = 7^2 + 4^2\\  
F(4,1)&= (65) = 1^2 + 8^2 = 7^2 + 4^2\\  
F(3,3)&= (73) = 3^2 + 8^2\\  
F(1,6)&= (85) = 7^2 +6^2 = 9^2 + 2^2\\  
F(4,2)&= (85) = 7^2 +6^2 = 9^2 + 2^2\\  
F(2,5)&= (89) = 5^2 + 8^2\\  
F(3,4)&= (97) = 9^2 + 4^2\\  
F(5,1)&= (101)= 1^2 + 10^2\\  
F(4,3)&= (109)= 3^2 + 10^2\\  
F(3,5)&= (125)= 5^2 + 10^2 = 11^2 + 2^2\\  
F(5,2)&= (125)= 5^2 + 10^2 = 11^2 + 2^2\\  
F(4,4)&= (137)= 11^2 + 4^2\\  
F(5,3)&= (153)= 3^2 + 12^2\\  
F(4,5)&= (169)= 5^2 + 12^2\\  
F(5,4)&= (185)= 13^2 + 4^2  = 11^2 + 8^2\\  
F(5,5)&= (221)= 5^2 + 14^2 = 11^2 + 10^2\\  
F(5,6)&= (261)= 15^2 + 6^2\\
&\vdots\\
\end{align*}
In the spreadsheet excerpt below (similar to
[Cantor's pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function)
) we can see $\textbf{bolded}$ numbers which break with the "obvious" pattern.

[image]

Still,  the $\space k^{th} \space$ triple in any set is predictable.   For instance,  the $\space 13^{th} \space $ number in $\space Set_{13}\space$ is
$\space F(13,13)=1613= 13^2 + 38^2,\space$ and the $\space 5001^{st} \space $ number in $\space Set_{5000}\space$  is $\space 
F(5000,5001)=(250010001) = 5001^2 + 15000^2.$

Comment: That is perfect @poetasis -- thank you.